Finf the segment EC in the triangle ABC below
In a triangle $ABC$ where $AB = 6$ and $BC = 9$; the extension of the bisector of angle ABC intersects the (perpendicular) bisector of $AC$ at $P$ and is then drawn: PE⊥BC.
Calculate $EC$.
(Answer:1,5)
I try:

$\frac{OA}{6} = \frac{CO}{9}\implies CO =\frac{3OA}{2}$
$\triangle CEF \sim \triangle CEG$
$\frac{SE}{GF}=\frac{CE}{CG}=\frac{CS}{CF}$
$CF = AF$
$\triangle CEF \sim \triangle PFS$
$\frac{SE}{SF}=\frac{CE}{FP}=\frac{CS}{PS}$
How can I continue?

Can you clarify the similar triangles in your attempt? $\triangle CEG$ is a line segment...

Reflect $A$ over $BP$ to $A' \in BC$. Notice two things:

$|PA'|=|PA|=|PC|$, so $\triangle PA'C$ is isosceles with $|PA'|=|PC|$, thus $|A'E|=|EC|$.
$|BA'| = |BA| = 6$

To conclude, the remaining $|A'C|$ part is $9-6=3$, hence $|A'E|=\boxed{|EC|=1.5}$.

Thanks, but Could you explain better? What guarantees that A' will be in BC and PA = PA'? And why BA' = BA? Is it a resolution by geometric design?

@petaarantes FYI, that also confused me a bit slightly. Instead, consider drawing from $A$ the line segment that is perpendicular with $PB$, with it meeting $PB$ at $Q$ and $BC$ at $A'$. Thus, we have $\measuredangle BQA=\measuredangle BQA`=90^{\circ}$, and it's also given that $\measuredangle ABQ=\measuredangle A'BQ$, so we also have $\measuredangle QAB=\measuredangle QA'B$. Since $PB$ is in common, we have $\triangle ABQ\cong \triangle A'BQ$, so the OP's point #$2$ follows. Also, $\lvert AQ\rvert=\lvert A'Q\rvert$ and, thus, since both $\triangle PQA$ and $\triangle PQA'$ are ...

(cont.) right-angled, they are congruent, i.e., $\lvert PA'\rvert=\lvert PA\rvert$, with $\lvert PA\rvert=\lvert PC\rvert$ due to $F$ being the perpendicular bisector of $AC$.

all of it is due to $BP$ being the angle bisector. alternatively, one can construct the point $A'$ by drawing a perpendicular from $A$ to $BP$ and letting it intersect $BC$ at point $A'$

@JohnOmielan Very good explanation..thank you my friend

You can also note that, since $P$ is the intersection of the perpendicular bisectors of $AC$ and $AA'$, it is the circumcenter of $\triangle AA'C$. Therefore, the foot ($E$) of the perpendicular to $A'C$ is the midpoint.


You can also reflect C over PE and show that triangles ABG and GBC' are congruent, so $BC'=6\rightarrow CC'=3\Rightarrow CE=\frac {CC'}2=1.5$
